# How to evaluate ACL in Kohana 3.2 HTTP_Cache cached requests

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

After a recent upgrade to an in-house K3.2 REST based API I'm looking at making use of the internal request caching mechanism.

I'm looking at caching at the initial request level (so within the application index.php):

1) is this a fundamentally flawed idea?

My initial request looks like this:

```php
$obj_r = Request::factory(TRUE, HTTP_Cache::factory('memcache'))
    ->execute();

echo $obj_r->send_headers()
    ->body();
```

This all works great, except that requesting from a source that matches the internal basic_cache_key_generator will simply (and correctly) return the cached response - skipping any application ACL rules (which normally occur as part of a parent ::before function

2) Is the correct approach here to provide a custom cache_key_callback as an option to the HTTP_Cache::factory call? - within this custom callback I can then build and evaluate the ACL rules denying access to the resource if required

Sincere apologies if i've missed any docs relating to this, I have looked!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `$this->response->check_cache($cache_key, $this->request)` instead. Your page will send ETag based on that custom callback.